# How do you say Jinx?

Tags: phrase, colloquial

So in English you can "jinx" someone (Jinx you owe me a coke!). Is there a phrase in German that is the equivalent?

English reference: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children's_game)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_%28children%27s_game%29)

Comment: We don't play that in Germany. Instead, we have a thing where when two people say the same thing at the same time, they both get to make a wish. Not sure how widely spread that is, though.

Comment: A friend of mine and I, we used to count how often that happens; but other than that...um, well nothing more. - But I remember there was a game where you had to trick people so that they look into, um the rounded opening when you put index and thumb together. Quite stupid that game but if someone did so, he got beaten on the shoulder - similar to what's been described in your link. However, I cannot remember what you said.. I guess something like "Haha, du hast reingeguckt" or such a thing maybe?! Do other remember that game? Does that have a name, or was it only a stupid idea of my classmates

Comment: There is a custom (among grown-ups rather) to say "Na, beim nächsten Mal gibst du aber einen aus!" if you happen to meet the same (acquainted) person repeatedly the same day (provided this repetition is unexpected, i.e. this is not your next-door neighbour or co-worker)

Comment: @Em1: Yes, it was [not only you](http://forum.worldofplayers.de/forum/threads/580008-Woher-kommt-das-Spiel-Reingeschaut). *Augenhöhe* disqualified. *Reingeschaut!*, or *Reingeguckt!*. [This site](http://www.bongoloch.de/) calls it *Bongoloch* (but I never heard this term before).

Comment: @unor Hahaha. Good catch. I haven't heard that term either.

Comment: @unor “Bongoloch” sounds so… dirty. ;)

Comment: Ich kenne den Ausdruck "zwei Idioten, ein Gedanke" und habe noch ein oder zwei seltsame Begriffe gehört, auf die ich aber nicht komme, und die auch nicht erwähnt wurden bislang. Scheint so, als ob jeder Straßenblock seinen eigenen Jargon dafür hat. Takkats Sachen habe ich auch noch nie gehört, vor allem aber nicht Jinx selbst. `Teekesselchen` war glaube ich einer, aber sicher bin ich nicht. Das ist ja auch ein Spiel wo man Begriffe mit 2 Bedeutungen sucht.

Comment: From the mostly downvoted, or non-voted answers we have so far it appears that it is very obscure what usage of *"jinx"* you would like to transfer to German. Please [edit] your question for clarification (e.g. give us an example with context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The German version is "Chips Cola". It doesn't seem to be very far spread but you can find a few results via Google.

Comment: Never heard it, but nice find anyway :)

Comment: @Takkat: I actually remembered it from my childhood.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is:

### NO

I also never ever have heard of any of the games mentioned in other answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

One usage of saying **"Jinx!"** is when two people coincidentally say or do the same thing in the same moment. In contemporary German there is not such a short phrase but we may say something along the line of

> *"Du hast mir das Wort aus dem Mund genommen."*
>   *"Zeitgleich!"* or *"Gleichzeitig!"*
>   *"Das war ja Telepathie!"*
>   *"Kannst Du Gedanken lesen?"*

Some of these still have some superstitious element inherent (*Telepathie* = telepathy, *Gedankenlesen* = reading thoughts) but probably not to the extent the English counterpart has.

This was not always the case. There was regionally different superstition depicted in phrases used after two people said or did the same simultaneously. Those proverbs are mostly lost today:

> *Die haben eine arme Seele erlöst.*
>   *Die haben einen Schneider in den Himmel gelupft.*
>   *Eine Pfaffenköchin wurde aus dem Fegefeuer erlöst.*

<sup>Quelle: Hoffmann-Krayer et al.: Handwörterbuch des deutschen Aberglaubens</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The game isn't played in Germany much, if at all. There is a card game with a similar game mechanic, called "Krieg und Frieden" ([Link to German language Wikipedia)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_royale) or the derivative "Autoquartett" ([Link to English language Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Trumps). In these games the equivalent word for `jinx` is `Stich`. So, children adopting these games into jinx-like games would probably say `Stich`.

Comment: Never heard that

Comment: "to jinx" is in German "verhexen" or "mit einem Fluch belegen". A "jinx" (noun) is in German either "Fluch einer Hexe" or "die von einer Hexe verfluchte Person". Non of this meanings has any similarities to German "Stich". I don't know an english equivalent to "Stich". "Einen Stich machen" means to win a round at a card game.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast But the `jinx` as used in the question has nothing to do with `verhexen` either.